# HTML select option multiline value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `select` and `option` tags in my HTML page.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock.">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock.</option>
</select>
```

My last option has a big text retrieving from database and it is bigger than the select box.

Is it possible to make this `<option>` value **double line** or **multi line** by `CSS` or `Javascript` like below ?

[image: Option Select]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746824/can-you-have-multiple-lines-in-an-option-element) but I could not understand.

**UPDATE:**

Somebody marked my question as already answered [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44). But this link is not working.

I can limit my character count by `sql query`. But this is not the solution.

Comment: your html is buggy, it should be `<option value=''>content</option>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word wrap options in a select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587942/word-wrap-options-in-a-select-list)

Comment: @Manoz It is just for example. I didn't forget the `value` part for the best of my knowledge. Please, if you have the answer, post it.

Comment: In the solution you found it says that it doesn't work on all the browsers and that you should try adding tags inside `<option></option>` item

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build a <select> with multiline option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368502/how-can-i-build-a-select-with-multiline-option)

Comment: @Raj, Maybe the result is no.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258723/fix-size-drop-down-with-long-text-in-options-restricted-view-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try [jQuery-Selectric](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric) this plugin which possibly solve your issue.

Comment: OK so jQuery isn't a solution to anything frankly.  Fantastic framework but it's not an answer to an HTML question and certainly doesn't apply to any of the newer frameworks (that first emulated then dumped jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Nope it is not possible with the standard `option` tag. Try plugin menu's, there are tons. [like this](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu)