# how can i display multiple lines text caption in select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

i am using `<select>` to make a list inside a select tag element with fixed width. let's say it is 200px.

this is my problem : my caption was cropped due the `<select>` fix width.

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAqs2.jpg)

---

and this is my expectation :

### [expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrUy1.jpg)

any suggestion to achieve that goal without editing the option caption?

Comment: See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562621/html-select-option-multiline-value. It might help

Comment: Use white-space:normal; for the li check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_white-space&preval=nowrap   .Please provide the codes which you have tried for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can do with the css which is below:

```
<style>
 .test {word-wrap:break-word;} 
</style>


<html><header><title></title></header>
<body>
<select class="test">  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, browsers don't provide any possibility to format this.

You could either use fake Selects (like Bootstrap e.g.) or add at least the title to the option to provide the whole text on mouseover:

```
<option title="Insert title of way too long Option text here">way too long Option text</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly style `<options>` tag because it supports limited styles and styling for these elements is handled by the user's OS [ref here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx).

and Its supporting styles are

`font-family`
`font-*`
`color`
`background-color`

You can style it by using JQuery third party [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/select/)