# How to delete a folder? In VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

'' I created a folder like this and it contains many databases. When I'm about to submit again the button there was an error of "Database already exist" i am saying that I'm about to delete the src folder instead of the databases. What should I do then? What code to use?

```
Dim testPath1 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\DDC OS" & "\CARD DECK" & "\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "\" & batchFolderName & "\Compare"
Dim testPath5 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\DDC OS" & "\CARD DECK" & "\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "\" & batchFolderName & "\Entry1"
Dim testPath2 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\DDC OS" & "\CARD DECK" & "\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "\" & batchFolderName & "\Entry2"
Dim testPath3 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\DDC OS" & "\CARD DECK" & "\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "\" & batchFolderName & "\Images"
Dim testPath4 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\CBATCH"
Dim testPath6 As String = Form1.Dir_folder.Text & "\CBATCH" & "\CardDeck" & "\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath5) Then
    MkDir(testPath5)
End If
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath1) Then
    MkDir(testPath1)
End If
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath2) Then
    MkDir(testPath2)
End If
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath3) Then
    MkDir(testPath3)
End If
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath4) Then
    MkDir(testPath4)
End If
If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testPath6) Then
    MkDir(testPath6)
End If
```

Comment: Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: If you don't format and ask a proper question,your question will be deleted. So follow the link suggested by @WaiHaLee

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you mean by "submit again". Are you clicking the same button again to create the same folders?

Comment: Try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+delete+a+folder+VB.NET

Comment: yes. creating folders and deleting folders are in the same button.
I was about to delete it when it has been exist.

Comment: @Vincent i tried that a while ago. nothings happened

Comment: Is your error "Database already exists", or "Directory already exists" ?

Comment: it was "Database already exists"

Comment: and because of having plenty of databases. i just need to delete the source folder instead of deleting each one until it's become none.

Comment: because if that happen, many dialog box will appear. Example: "Database already Exist", "Do you want to Delete it?" x10

Comment: Well, if you tried all the different ways to do it and none works, perhaps your doing something wrong? On StackOverflow you are mostly supposed to share _what you have tried_. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i got it now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  My answer had nothing to do with using databases.  Which is why I apologised for misreading your original question.  I should delete it and let someone else answer.

Comment: Hi David, could you help me browse an mdb file through using openfiledialog and update inside of it through datagridview tool?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest MkDir isnt the quickest way to create directories, but for consistency, just use

```
RmDir(testPath1)
```

A better performing way would be to use..

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(testPath1)
```

to create a directory and ..

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(testPath1,FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
```

to delete it/

Comment: but looks like database inside of the folders has been locked. what codes I will be using to unlock it so that the folder will be deleted?

Comment: how about releasing(unlock) database? so that i can delete the folder immediately using a button?

Comment: Well,  you'll have to close all the open connections to the databases that you want to delete.  If they have been opened using your program then it should be straightforward. If the connections have been opened by another program,  it's more of a problem.

Comment: i have closed it uging connection.close() but still not working. </3

Comment: how about counting the rows inside of the database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You just want to know how to count the number of rows in a database table?

Comment: yah. with the use of vb.net, anyway i am using ADOX.Catalog and OleDb to create a database.

Comment: just use the    .Rows.Count     property of the datatable

Comment: how it is? sorry im just a beginner.

Comment: hey! do you know how to connect the databases through using openfiledialogbox?

Comment: Hi David, can you help me select multiple items in Listbox?

Comment: To be honest I don't have enough free time to write programs. Getting all the information is very time consuming. I did find this link for you about multi selecting listbox items though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488211/multi-select-list-box

Comment: i get it now David, thanks to you. How about create a copy of mdb and convert it into excel? do you know how?

Comment: Not a clue I'm afraid. Do you have a copy of MS Access? You might be able to export the mdb as a csv file and import it into access. To do it programattically,I dont have any experience of working with excel files. There seems to be plenty of results on google to convert mdb to excel files though.

Comment: ah, okay. anyway, i've been searching for an hours but it seems those given codes by google are not compatible by mine. it seems like, maybe i will going to solve it by my own. </3

Comment: You could try posting another question on Stack Overflow, but as you havent got any code for it yet, you might not get much help. You could also try the Stack exchange Super User site.

Comment: i got my limit on Stack Overflow, it seems 3days more left so that i can post a question.

Comment: Well. If you dont post a question then you wont get an answer, but if you do post a question, then you might get an answer. Trying is better than not trying :-)

Comment: Wew, i am just trying to say that i've been blocked by stackoverflow that cause me to not post a question. but i do really like to post, it helped me a lot after all.

Comment: Oops. Maybe you could create a new account with a different email address. and make sure to have a look here [ask] and here [mcve] to post better questions :-) Do you mind if I ask what you got blocked for?

Comment: It seems like if you've asked for more than 7 questions, you will be blocked by 1week and 3days. Maybe because I only have 5 reputation yet.

Comment: Hi David, could you please give me a sample of zooming using mousewheel and cropping using button. Please I need it badly. :'( help me pls! :'(