# How to control the width of select tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of countries, some with a very long name:

```
<select name=countries>
 <option value=af>Afghanistan</option>
 <option value=ax>Åland Islands</option>
 ...
 <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 ...
</select>
```

By default, the select box would be as long as the longest option in the list. I want to create a select box such that it exhibits the default behaviour when viewed from a wide browser window, but fit in nicely to 90% of container width when viewed from a narrow browser window, smaller than the length of the longest option.

I tried `min-width: 90%;`, but it didn't work. Can this be done by CSS styling alone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294040/how-to-expand-select-option-width-after-the-user-wants-to-select-an-option

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: I think that doesn't answer my question. Does it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make select elements shrink to max-width percent style within fieldset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672586/how-to-make-select-elements-shrink-to-max-width-percent-style-within-fieldset)

Comment: @GregD, both questions are mine, they may look the same, but they are not duplicate of each other. The other question is specific to a problem I have while adopting the selected answer in this question.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow - ok, no problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

USE `style="max-width:90%;"`

```
<select name=countries  style="max-width:90%;">
 <option value=af>Afghanistan</option>
 <option value=ax>Åland Islands</option>
 ...
 <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 ...
</select>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nGFnj/3/)

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question. Can you read again? Thanks.

Comment: @BenHuh : Sorry. Let me try once again.

Comment: Using your solution, the select tag will be longer than necessary in a wide browser window.

Comment: @BenHuh : No, it won't.. Haven't you checked the live demo?

Comment: I have checked. Both showing the same length, apparently it doesn't work on the latest firefox browser.

Comment: Mine is 11, It works well in mine. I've checked it in IE9 and Chrome they are perfect too. Hav you teied resizing the result pane to smaller?

Comment: Yes, it did work. Oh mine.. I realise the reason why it doesn't work is due to me using monospace font-family. Thanks.

Comment: I just checked this in 2018 and I do not see a difference between the two methods in Chrome.

Comment: it seems your solution does not work in contemporary browsers

Comment: I just checked this in 2020 with chrome and Mac OS I do not see a difference between the two methods

Comment: In 2023, this is not a good solution. This "solution" just shrinks the width of the dropdown by 10%, but does not take into consideration anything.

Answer (score 8):

You've simply got it backwards. Specifying a minimum width would make the select menu always be *at least* that width, so it will continue expanding to 90% no matter what the window size is, also being at least the size of its longest option.

You need to use `max-width` instead. This way, it will let the select menu expand to its longest option, but if that expands past your set maximum of 90% width, crunch it down to that width.

Comment: But how to crunch it down? Can I have two max-widths?

Comment: The browser does all the crunching.

Comment: Apparently, max-width doesn't work on select tag. I am using the lastest version of firefox, not sure about the rest.

Comment: You can have different values of `max-width` (`auto` included) in different situations with the help of Media Queries. The latter will help you manage what you think a "narrow/wide browser window" for your particular design, if needed. Unrelated, browsers have a LOT of freedom when it's related to forms. Like cropping options larger than select in IE6/7...

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations: good point. Thanks, I will certainly look into media queries. Can we have a confirmation that `max-width` on select is working in other browsers. Just a yes/no will do. Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't clear for me either but no it won't: you can't define the width of a parent based on the width of its chidlren, and that's what select / option are. `max-width: 90%` works at least in Fx, but that's 90% of the parent `div`...

Comment: Additional note on MQ: smartphones take extra care of select/option, they've dedicated UI for that so no need to restrict width or whatever, that would be counter-productive I think. As for tablet (circa 768px), same for iPad but I don't know what others like Playbook BlackBerry and Samsung and countless others do

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations: thanks for your input regarding smartphones. You understood my intention quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Add div wrapper

```
<div id=myForm>
<select name=countries>
 <option value=af>Afghanistan</option>
 <option value=ax>Åland Islands</option>
 ...
 <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 ...
</select>
</div>
```

and then write CSS

```
#myForm select { 
width:200px; }

#myForm select:focus {
width:auto; }
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I can find this solution in the future:

**I tried very hard** to find a solution strictly in CSS, but nothing worked as I'd liked.

I am posting here my jQuery solution that works. It shrinks and expands the select based on the selected option.

```js
    // Auto resizing the SELECT element according to selected OPTION's width
    $(function() {
        let arrowWidth = 25;
    
        $.fn.resizeselect = function(settings) {
          return this.each(function() { 
    
            $(this).change(function(){
              let $this = $(this);
    
              // get font-weight, font-size, and font-family
              let style = window.getComputedStyle(this)
              let { fontWeight, fontSize, fontFamily } = style
    
              // create test element
              let text = $this.find("option:selected").text();
              let $test = $("<span>").html(text).css({
                "font-size": fontSize, 
                "font-weight": fontWeight, 
                "font-family": fontFamily,
                "visibility": "hidden" // prevents FOUC
              });
    
              // add to body, get width, and get out
              $test.appendTo($this.parent());
              let width = $test.width();
              $test.remove();
    
              // set select width
              $this.width(width + arrowWidth);
    
              // run on start
            }).change();
    
          });
        };
    
        // Run by default 100ms after page load
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("select.filter-dropdown").resizeselect();         
        }, 100);   
    })
```

```css
select.filter-dropdown{
   width: 150px;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <select class="filter-dropdown">
    <option>All Options</option>
      <option>Value 1</option>
      <option>Long Modifications</option>
      <option>Your very welcome for saving your live.</option>
  </select>

  <select class="filter-dropdown">
    <option value="">All Service Types</option>
      <option>Short Value</option>
      <option>Longer Value here</option>
      <option>Extremely looooooooooooooong value here</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```