# How to set width of a multiple select?

Tags: html

I want to set default width of multiple select elements :

[image]

How to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this,

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
```

or

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 10em;">
```

Answer (score 3):

The same way as any other element. You write a selector that matches the element (e.g. a select element with a multiple attribute) and then use the width property.

Width applies by default to replaced inline elements (such as selects).

```
select[multiple] {
    width: 7em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This in css

```
select[multiple=multiple] {width: <default width you want>px ;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `max-width` property on `style`.

Ex:

```
<select name=countries  style="max-width:90%;">
 <option value=af>Afghanistan</option>
 <option value=ax>Åland Islands</option>
 ...
 <option value=gs>South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 ...
</select>
```

More information: [How to control the width of select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671614/how-to-control-the-width-of-select-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "size" attribute like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select size="3">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```