# How to fix the width of select tag in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fix the width of select tag in html. But what i want is that whenever we select an item from it, that item's width should also get changed to the width of the select tag so that each item is fully visible in the select tag on selection.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're open to javascript, yes.

Comment: yes i am open to javascript. How can i do this?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A query for `How to fix the width of select tag in html?` turns up plenty of answers.

Comment: e.g. [How to control the width of select tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671614/how-to-control-the-width-of-select-tag)

Comment: or [Set width of dropdown element in HTML select dropdown options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1702186)

Comment: No idea really, but try searching here in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/682764/938236