# How to control the width of select2 select tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

Setting the width of select2 using css is overridden by the javascript call of the select2

```
// javascript
$(function() {
  renderSelect("select");
});

# HAML example (Rails)
 = select_tag "countries", options_for_select(@countries), class: 'some-ignored-css-class'
```

related: [How to control the width of select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671614/how-to-control-the-width-of-select-tag)

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't javascript, the issue is that you're not preserving the CSS.

The *only* way to set the width is to use CSS. Even your JS sets the CSS ([`.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)):

> The difference between `.css(width)` and `.width()` is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`). They both set the CSS "style" element

A better way is to either set the CSS on a "container" element, or make sure you're persisting the CSS whenever you call the `renderSelect` function:

---

[Container](https://jsfiddle.net/LL08tkde/)

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.container select { width: 50px; }

#app/views...
.container= select_tag "countries", options_for_select(@countries)
```

Using a container will allow you to set the CSS on the *container*, removing the need for the class on the `select` itself. Whilst it means adding a container div, it will give you the most autonomy.

--

JS

The alternative will be to change the `renderSelect` function to take the class of the current `select` & append it to the new element.

Since I don't know your `renderSelect` function, I can only provide that level of suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

A solution is to javascript again

```
// javascript
$(function() {
  renderSelect("select");
  $("div#s2id_countries").width(300);
});

# HAML example (Rails)
 = select_tag "countries", options_for_select(@countries), class: 'some-ignored-css-class'
```

*ahh, Javascript, the cause of, and solution to, all of life's problems*

(any improvements?)