# CSS cannot be applied to a form element through javascript, if doctype is set

Tags: javascript, html

i have textbox like this:

```
<input id="patId1" type="text" name="patId1" value="">
```

when the page loads, a script is called which sets the width of the textbox. That code is as follows :

```
document.getElementById("patId1").style.width = document.getElementById("patId2").offsetWidth;
```

where, patId2 is a dropdown list (select tag). Basically what i am trying to do is setting the width of textbox same as that of the width of dropdown list.

Now, if DOCTYPE is set, then the above script doesn't work. But if it is not set, the width is applied.

Any help.

Comment: There is no reason I can think of to create new web pages without a doctype.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you setting, specifically? And is this happening with several web browsers? Or just with one? Last question: Which OS are you developing on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `offsetWidth` will be a Number. The CSS `width` property accepts a *length*. Lengths (other than `0`) must have units. In quirks mode, browsers violate the CSS specification and assume `px` units.

```
document.getElementById("patId1").style.width = document.getElementById("patId2").offsetWidth + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

Append "px" to offsetWidth of dropdown . JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/ysj2t/1/: `document.getElementById("patId1").style.width = document.getElementById("patId2").offsetWidth + "px";`

Answer (score 0):

**There is a simpler way of doing this,** and I've re-purposed the code from the following post by @cychan:

Link:

[How to expand 'select' option width after the user wants to select an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294040/how-to-expand-select-option-width-after-the-user-wants-to-select-an-option)

Here is the general approach:

```
<div id="select-wrapper-01" style="width: 180px; overflow: hidden;">
    <select style="width: auto;" name="abc" id="10">
        <option value="-1">Any</option>
        <option value="123">123</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Now you might be saying, "Wait a minute? My largest select option is not 180px wide!"

In that case, remove the `width` and `overflow` style attributes from the `div`.

Then use javascript to provide the appropriate width to the surrounding div, something like:

```
var actualWidth = document.getElementById("patId2").offsetWidth;
document.getElementById("select-wrapper-01").style.width = actualWidth + 'px';
```

[image]

Here's a working copy on jsfiddle. Nothing fancy, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/acegyver/eTEuk/

You can try playing with the select `option`s, make them longer, or shorter, and see how the `select` will adapt dynamically.

Give credit where credit is due: As I've said, I tweaked the code from an existing post by @cychan. The implementation that works for your question is by me.