# HTML Dropdown Auto-Width Adjust

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've created a dropdown that has issues resizing according to what's selected. I'm using the following stackoverflow answer as inspiration to resize my dropdown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20091985/3166468

For some reason, although the resizing happens, it always resizes either too much or too little. Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yadhwb97/3/

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="real_dropdown">
    <option disabled="">Options</option>
    <option value="long">Something super long in here</option>
    <option value="short">Short</option>
  </select>
</div>
<select id="width_tmp_select">
  <option id="width_tmp_option"></option>
</select>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').change(function(){
    $("#width_tmp_option").html($('.dropdown option:selected').text()); 
    $(this).width($("#width_tmp_select").width()+30);  
  });
});
```

When you select the dropdown options, you'll see how it resizes either too much or too little. How can I make the resizing work correctly?

Comment: You can always increase the `width value` i.e. instead of `+30` use something else. However, getting an accurate solution may be a bit tricky. You would have to store initial width for each option in an object with `name` and `width` and then on change pull the values based on selection and set the width. For now, you can set the width to 280 when option long is selected, but you need to consider future/other options that will be added later.

Comment: check my solution, it's working perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343177/1243247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is your hidden dropdown has diff font size. 
add `font-size: 16px;` to `#width_tmp_select` and should work now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').change(function(){
    $("#width_tmp_option").html($('.dropdown option:selected').text()); 
    $(this).width($("#width_tmp_select").width());  
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://secure.echobox.com/img/dropdown_arrow.png) no-repeat right transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-size: 18px 5px;
}

.dropdown select {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  font-family: "proxima-nova", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #56646E;
}

#width_tmp_select{
  display : none;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2>
This "custom" dropdown doesn't resize correctly.
</h2>
<div class="dropdown">
  <select id="real_dropdown">
    <option disabled="">Options</option>
    <option value="long">Something super long in here</option>
    <option value="short">Short</option>
  </select>
</div>
<select id="width_tmp_select">
  <option id="width_tmp_option"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: check my solution, it's working perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343177/1243247

Answer (score -1):

With CSS my friend!! Please rep me :)

```css
#real_dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
#width_tmp_select {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```