# Dropdown select box min width and max width

Tags: html, css

Dropdown select box min width and max width. I don't set the width of the select box, since I want when the screen get resize the select box get resize too so far I have the following code only work on Firefox but no IE

```
#building select, option {
  min-width: 360px;       
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: hey you can use this answer - [dropdown-auto-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817102/html-dropdown-auto-width-adjust)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in ie: https://fiddle.jshell.net/f7jkg3LL/2/ can you explain exactly what is wrong with your code or replicate the error in a [MCVE]

Comment: my select data is select from db , it can be every long, but when there is not data the depend select box can be very short , there is why I want to set something at  width ,                                                                                                         but in ie when the depend select box is not data , it did not keep the min-width