# Problem with white space in option list of a Select in chrome version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, select

I have a problem with the HTML "Select" Options rendering in google Chrome, it has a white space among the list of option, on the right side, its happening on sites that invoke another site with the select list within an iframe.

It could be a chrome bug but i truly want to solve it in the simplest and least impact way. Other fact is it only happen on a screen resolution of 1920x1080 and a scale and layout of a 125% (on win 10)
One of the examples is in this page: [How to expand 'select' option width after the user wants to select an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294040/how-to-expand-select-option-width-after-the-user-wants-to-select-an-option) and see the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmEyM.png) this is how I see it.

another example is in this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup
see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdoI3.png) and also have an iframe and I don't really know what's causing it.

Can any one please give me a suggestion how can I solve this? or is a well known BUG of chrome? I have chrome version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Thank you for all your help regarding this issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in *this* question. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>`, or press Ctrl+M).

Comment: Sorry, but I have not been able to reproduce the issue on example code, thats the reason i need help, to understand clearly what's causing it, and how can i build a solution for it. thank you for all the help.